# Why declare Resource in try() while using try-with-resources

Tags: java, exception, java-7, try-with-resources

**The try-with-resources Statement**
Following is example from Java [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

As per doc ,

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

My question is,
Why do I need to declare resource within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. *(like BuffereReader above)*

BuffereReader implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`

So why not support something like this,

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
        try{
            BufferedReader br =
                       new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))
            return br.readLine();
        }
    }
```

And just implicitly close resource object once out of try.
(As it has implemeted AutoCloseable)

I just had a thought, Why change in syntax.

Please Read Question Properly, Its Regarding Syntax Only.

Comment: maybe that way compiler knows where to search for open resources ;)

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar how has this question duplicated that question?

Comment: because it contains answer to your question, See the most voted answer @tnadeV

Comment: Because computers like certainty. The JVM should exactly know which resource should be closed. Imagine you want to use several resources, some of them should be automatically closed and the others not.

Comment: @DannyLo hmm your right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some situations you don't want to close immediately the `AutoCloseable` resource. For example:

```
static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String path) {
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        return new BufferedReader(fr);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        // handle somehow
    }
}
```

In this case you cannot close the `fr` upon the exit of the `try` block. Otherwise the returned `BufferedReader` will be invalid. So you should explicitly specify when you want to close the resource. That's why special syntax was invented.

Comment: I too had same thought,Thanks

Comment: Considering Danny Lo and EJP answers too

Answer (score 4):

Because it would change the semantics of existing program. A new syntax was needed for this new feature.

Comment: Yes , I didn't though this , Thank you :)